# Suddenly not able to SSH into AWS Linux instance using ec2-user

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-ec2

Today **all of a sudden** I am not able to SSH into my AWS linux instance using **ec2-user** as username.

I was able to do it yesterday.

I have searched for this and found that all things are in place, Security group, Key etc.

Getting this error.

`login as: ec2-user
Server refused our key
ec2-user@XX.XX.XX.XXX's password:`

Since this is the root user. How can I recover access?

Comment: Did you try rebooting the instance?

Comment: @JayMcTee: Yes I rebooted it, did not work.

Comment: Well, given the error, there must be something wrong with that key, It seems like it's there and found, but not as it was before. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20864224/putty-getting-server-refused-our-key-error for debugging hints.

Comment: @JayMcTee: I tried these solutions, but unfortunately I do not have any other root user access to modify permissions of files/directories or to modify `sshd_config` file. So I cannot even check the error in log.

Comment: On the client side, you can manually eyeball and verify your key hasn't been corrupted. Replacing it with your backed up key might be a good idea too. As a side note, this highlights why one wouldn't want to use a root account as the regular and only means of access.

Comment: @JayMcTee: This is happening on all the machines/clients from which I am accessing the server. I have other accounts and they use password use password authentication, but they are less privileged. I use `root/ec2-user` account only to create new users or to do root specific tasks.
Is there a way to regain access? Using AWS console dashboard or any other way?

Comment: My bad, my home folder was mounted on another EBS volume and I was trying every solution on root volume. Now I resolved the issue.